# Side laying flexion: what muscles worked?

Tags: injury, shoulders, rotator-cuff, rehabilitation, shoulder-cuff

I had a case of shoulder impingement a while back and it got 85–90% better with physio, but then found this exercise online which appears to be helping to finish my recovery:

[image]

It really feels like it's doing the trick... but I'm just wondering what muscles it's actually working?

I presume it targets around the rotator cuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This movement can be understood by breaking it down into it's parts.

---

**Position:**  Side-lying 
**Shoulder:** (GH Joint) 0 degree's of Flexion.
**Elbow:** Fully Extended. 
**Movement:** Shoulder Flexion from 0 to 90 degrees *(gravity minimized)*

---

In order to keep your hand parallel to the floor, and modulate the force needed to complete the movement, scapula stabilizers (retractors).

**Scapula Retractors:**
1.) Lower Trapezius
2.) Rhomboids *(Major and Minor)*

---

What is great about this exercise - the shoulder flexion provides various degrees of muscle activation throughout the range of motion (ROM) also known as dynamic stability.